# Angular application File upload generating same file name when image is uploaded via camera capture in ios device

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, typescript

We have a progressive web application built using Angular. When we upload files/images from the browser it works fines. When we use the file upload control in ios it gives us the options to "Chose from library" or "take picture". When I take multiple pictures and try to upload the files, all files are getting the same name. Files should be having different names when clicked as photo from ios. Following is the code for the file upload:

HTML:

```
<div class="flex"> 
                <!--img src="images/Clip.svg" (click)="attachFileClick()" class="p-r-half"--> 
                <svg (click)="attachFileClick()" class="clip-icon m-r-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">
                    <path class="path" d="M5.45455 6.34091L18 6.34091C20.4109 6.34091 22.3636 8.53773 22.3636 11.25C22.3636 13.9623 20.4109 16.1591 18 16.1591H4.36364C2.85818 16.1591 1.63636 14.7845 1.63636 13.0909C1.63636 11.3973 2.85818 10.0227 4.36364 10.0227H15.8182C16.4182 10.0227 16.9091 10.575 16.9091 11.25C16.9091 11.925 16.4182 12.4773 15.8182 12.4773H5.45455V14.3182H15.8182C17.3236 14.3182 18.5455 12.9436 18.5455 11.25C18.5455 9.55636 17.3236 8.18182 15.8182 8.18182L4.36364 8.18182C1.95273 8.18182 0 10.3786 0 13.0909C0 15.8032 1.95273 18 4.36364 18H18C21.3164 18 24 14.9809 24 11.25C24 7.51909 21.3164 4.5 18 4.5L5.45455 4.5V6.34091Z" fill=""/>
                    </svg>
            </div>

<div class="hide" tabIndex="-1" *ngIf="!readOnly"> 
        <input [hidden]="true" tabIndex="-1" #fileControl type="file" name="file" id="{{attachButton}}" dir="ltr"
            class="inputfile1 white-text" [accept]="mimeTypes" (change)="attachFile($event)" autocomplete="off"
            multiple />
    </div>

TypeScript:
 public attachFileClick(): void {
        this.fileControl.nativeElement.click();
    }

    public attachFile(event: any): void {
        this.randomId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
        let totalSizeOfAllFiles = 0;
        let files: any = event.target.files;

}
```

Can you please let me know how we can get different file name when file is uploaded via camera from ios.